# QTP - How to remove the XmlNode from the xml document?

Tags: vbscript, qtp, xmldom

I want remove an xml node from an xml document, but I don't know which function can be used to achieve that. Could you please tell me how to do that?

```
Const XMLDataFile = "C:\TestData.xml"

xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.Async = False
xmlDoc.Load(XMLDataFile)

nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/bookstore/book/author[text()='name=admin']")

' get their names
For i = 0 To (nodes.Length - 1)
    Title = nodes(i).NodeValue
    MsgBox("The node will be deleted " & Title)

    'TODO: The expect code here

Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really a QTP question, it's an XML question.
Looking at [MS's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757828.aspx) I would say the following will probably work

```
nodes(i).parentNode.removeChild nodes(i)
```

Comment: Hi Motti,  I have tried this function and a series of vb functions before. They cannot work.  It seems the QTP script and vb|vb.net are little different.   Do you know the exactly function?

Comment: @robinqiao, you say they cannot work, what exactly happens? Is there an error or is there just no effect on the XML file? If the latter have you tried to save it back to disk after changing it?

Comment: Hi Motti, your solution is right. It cannot works, because I haven't setup the QTP on that workstation and I used the visual studio instead, so it throws an exception. I have tried it on the QTP today, it works now. The code is nodes(i).parentNode.removeChild(nodes(i)). Thanks for your kindly help and sorry for the confusion.